# Order of divs not updated to match order of items in list

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I've run into a strange problem and I'm not sure how to work around it.  I have a list of items which I render in a list table with the ability to change the sort order of the items displayed.

Each row also has a div:

```
<button @onclick="Sort">Test</button>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Transactions)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Id
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Description
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    Hello World
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>


@code {
    public void Sort()
    {
        Transactions = Transactions.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(x, null)).ToList();        
    }
}
```

When I run this, before I press the sort button I change the content of the first div in the first row from Hello world to anything else using element inspector in the browser console and then press the sort button.

The list is now displayed in reverse order as it should, but the first div in the first row still contains the modified content (when now it should be the last row div).

The above is a simplified representation of the problem, in my real app, the div is a component which contains displays a string variable internal to itself and which can change based on a user action within the component (Custom Select dropdown) and of course the same problem occurs.

How can I ensure the div for each row is actually tied to the order of the list items displayed?

** UPDATE **

I added the key attribute to the div but this just seems to reset the value back to what it was instead of preserving it:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in listResponse.Transactions)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Id
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Description
            </td>
            <td>
                <div @key=item.Id>
                    Hello World
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: You can use the @key modifier like this: @key="component instance" for each component when you use a loop to create the components

Comment: @enet I've modified my question to include the edit you suggested, adding the key did not help unfortunately as explained in my update

Comment: @key tracks internally but also sets the stack order of the elements by rendering them in order, the stack order is easily changed in css whatever your doing the css must be moving the divs or table row around and throwing the element stack order

Comment: @fuzzybear css is not an option unfortunately as I have the ability to sort by different columns in my real app.  Also, in my example I'm simply reversing the order of items, nothing else going on.

Comment: @key works for sure so something else must be going on, need more info to assist

Comment: @fuzzybear you can simply copy and paste the code in my question to reproduce the problem, there is no other code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **blazor** way is the use **@key** see [control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components)

```
@foreach (var item in Transactions)
{
  <tr @key="item">
      ...
  </tr>
}
```

you can also use css flex order, this directly controls the elements from css and will overide whatever blazor is doing, visually only!

also see [codepen](https://codepen.io/KittyGiraudel/pen/DRGgpw/d49b9854fac25043782a031769df7b50) example

if you do want to use css I'd use a for loop as we can add the index manually ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
{
   <div style="order: @i">1</div>       
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="order: 3">1</div>
  <div style="order: 2">2</div>
  <div style="order: 4">3</div> 
  <div style="order: 1">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was adding the @key to the <div> element instead of the <tr> and it seems key is scoped so this was important